# Explicitly setting an IConfiguration value in a typesafe way

Tags: c#, .net

I want to explicitly set a configuration value for my testing setup to dynamically accommodate what's being spun up for the tests.

I can do either of the below, but I want to do it in a more typesafe way. I can't seem to find the syntax for it. What am I missing?

```cs
builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:RecipeManagement"] = _dbContainer.ConnectionString;
// or
builder.Configuration.GetSection(ConnectionStringOptions.SectionName)["RecipeManagement"] = _dbContainer.ConnectionString;
```

Here's an options class I have if it's helpful

```cs
namespace RecipeManagement.Configuration;

public class ConnectionStringOptions
{
    public const string SectionName = "ConnectionStrings";

    public string RecipeManagement { get; set; } = String.Empty;
}

public static class ConnectionStringOptionsExtensions
{
    public static ConnectionStringOptions GetConnectionStringOptions(this IConfiguration configuration)
        => configuration.GetSection(ConnectionStringOptions.SectionName).Get<ConnectionStringOptions>();
}
```

Comment: Is this what you're referring to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0 ?

Comment: i've been there. maybe i missed it, but i just looked through again and still don't see anything in there that shows a typesafe way to do what's above. would love be proved wrong :-)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly... What I'm getting is that you want a way to bind strongly typed options to your appsettings.json? Maybe this post is more clear: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-how-to-acces-configurations-using-options-pattern/

Comment: *getting* what's in appsettings is fine. I want to *set* the value of a particular configuration in code in a way that doesn't use a magic string

Comment: Ahh... Now I understand. I'm not aware of a way of handling this without "magic strings"... I'm interested to see if there is, indeed, a way of doing this as it would be quite useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the below does work with typesafety and is what i'm going with for now, but i would hope there's a better way

```cs
namespace RecipeManagement.Configuration;

public class ConnectionStringOptions
{
    public const string SectionName = "ConnectionStrings";
    public const string RecipeManagementKey = nameof(RecipeManagement);

    public string RecipeManagement { get; set; } = String.Empty;
}

public static class ConnectionStringOptionsExtensions
{
    public static ConnectionStringOptions GetConnectionStringOptions(this IConfiguration configuration)
        => configuration.GetSection(ConnectionStringOptions.SectionName).Get<ConnectionStringOptions>();
}
```

and use it:

```cs
builder.Configuration.GetSection(ConnectionStringOptions.SectionName)[ConnectionStringOptions.RecipeManagementKey] = _dbContainer.ConnectionString;
```